# Difference in number of table rows in information_schema

Tags: mysql, mariadb

how can information_scheme table show different information rows when i'm counting the table with query :

```
select count(id) from mytable
```

and the other query :

```
SELECT 

   engine AS Engine, 
   table_name AS Table, 
   table_rows AS Rows, 
   round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) as Size

FROM

   information_schema.TABLES

WHERE

   table_schema = DATABASE()

ORDER BY 

   Size desc;
```

My Database Version : 10.1.33-MariaDB

Thanks for advice!

Comment: (This is a dup question.)  The 'problem' applies to InnoDB tables.

Answer (score 1):

The first query returns the correct value.

The second query gets the value from `information_schema.TABLES`, which purpose if to store statistics about each table. The point of this table if to help MySQL query optimizer to choose the best execution plan.

As a consequence, the order of magnitude should be correct, but this table must not be used to get an accurate rowcount.

Comment: There is no need for a solution. If you want an accurate rowcount, use your first query. You should never use the second query for anything but a rough estimate of the order of magnitude of the row count. As long as you do not have query optimizer issues, there is no need to worry about the discrepancy between those two values. You can run `analyze table mytable` if you want to update the estimate, but note that you will not get the exact value anyway, because only a sample of your table is used to perform the estimate.